# Query Formula using Google Sheets - count data from multiple columns and return results in a single column

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am trying to calculate a count of how many times a course is listed in different columns and return the count in a list of all the courses found in those columns.

I have a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P089orqmGnWdhKOxpx_RAwozIli3DbQzl0FNvTzV6ms/edit?usp=sharing) that shows the start of my formula...

query(UNIQUE({C2:C21; F2:F21;I2:I21}),"select C,F,I, count(C), count(F), count(I) where B is not null group by C,F,I")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear cells A23, A24 and B23 and then try in A23

```
=query({C2:C21; F2:F21;I2:I21},"select Col1, count(Col1) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 label Col1 'Fall Courses', Count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

and see if that helps?

If it does, you can repeat the same logic for 'winter' and 'spring'.

Alternatively, you can also try this single formula

```
=query(ArrayFormula(split(transpose(split(textjoin("~", true, regexreplace(C1:K1, "(Winter|Spring|Fall)", "_$1")&"_"&C2:K21), "~")), "_")), "Select Col3, Count(Col3) where Col3 <>'' group by Col3 pivot Col2", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks you JPV,  the first formula worked. I won't even attempt to figure out the syntax n your second formula..lol. When using an array of columns you used column numbers versus etters. How do you derermine when to use you column letters or numbers? Thanks for your help.